# How to find the next date in one column grouped by criteria in another column?

Tags: excel, max, formula, min

I am stuck on how to accomplish this in excel so need some help please.

I am have two columns: ID and Date

There can be multiple dates per ID so the ID can be listed more than one time. I need to set up another column with the "Next highest date" for that ID or blank if that is the highest date. Ultimately I need to calculate the difference between the two dates.

I have been googling for a while and have tried a few things but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using MINIFS:

[image]

The MINIFS part:

```
MINIFS($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7,$A2,$B$2:$B$7,">"&$B2)
```

works by selecting the minimum date where the ID matches and the date is greater than the current date.

The IF wrapper around the MINIFS just replaces zeros with empty strings.

```
=IF(MINIFS($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7,$A2,$B$2:$B$7,">"&$B2)=0,
    "",
    MINIFS($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7,$A2,$B$2:$B$7,">"&$B2)
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying with MINIFS but didn't have it set up correctly.  Appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. I always think it seems counter intuitive to use MINIFS (rather than MAXIFS) when you are trying to get a date higher than the current one.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assuming ID is in column A, the dates in column B, 10 lines entered in rows 2 to 11, and you want the highest date to be in column C, then enter:

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,$B$2:$B$11))
```

... and then copy down.

Inspired by:
https://exceljet.net/formula/max-if-criteria-match

Comment: Isn't the OP asking for the next highest date for each row? Not just the max date for each ID. In which case you could just do `=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$:11,$A2)`